# Will Jetty outperform netty in a blocking/ non reactive REST application

Tags: java, rest, jetty, netty, reactive

I understand the case for NETTY in a reactive non blocking application. But I was wondering if Jetty will outperform Netty in the classic case when we have a regular REST application with blocking / synchrone API. My guess is yes, why ?

Answer (score 0):

Both Jetty and Netty asynchronously handle incoming requests. There are a lot of service frameworks that uses Netty for handling the Protocol (HTTP) layer, then hand the request to a thread pool thread, see Helidon, gRPC java ...etc. Jetty does the same thing.

In my experience, Netty outperforms Jetty in blocking request handling scenario as well. However, in order to give an authoritative answer, someone needs to perform an unbiased comparative performance test.

Comment: Common logic does not say that. Common logic says each blocking request holds and exclusive thread. Netty comes out of the box with very limited number of threads. Common logic says Jetty will outperform it because it runs with more threads, I need a deeper answer than that.

Comment: With Netty, you should handle each blocking scenario with a threat from a different thread poll. You never use channel treads for blocking calls.

Comment: A thread pool that I introduce, or a threadpool that is available from netty itself ?

Comment: The simple answer is a thread pool you provide. This becomes really simple if you use latest java and loom

```
try (var executor = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) {
     executor.submit(() -> handleRequest(request) );
}```

The more complex answer: Netty can be configured with a complex thread management. Such as a specific handler using a different EventLoop for blocking calls. But I personally prefer the first option